# Middleware based on laravel route parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('users/{type}', ['as'=>'users.index', 'uses'=>'UserController@index', 'middleware' => ['can:user-index']])->where('type', '(members|enquiries)');
```

Can I use dynamic middleware here based on route parameter type.

Like If type is enquiries then middleware should be `'can:enquiries-index'`, similarly for members `'can:members-index'`.

I know this can be done in controller function with authorize method, but I am using all authorizations in route file only. SO wanted to keep this here only.

I am using Laravel Gates definition for authorizing routes:

In AuthServiceProvider@boot

```
    Gate::before(function ($user, $ability) {
        $permission = Permission::where('slug', $ability)->first();
        return $user->hasPermissionTo($permission);
    });
```

Laravel Version: 7.9.2

PHP Version: 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do dynamic middleware but you don't have to do it in controller too. You may do something like that; You bind two middleware to that route.

```
Route::get('users/{type}', ['as'=>'users.index', 'uses'=>'UserController@index', 'middleware' => ['can:members-index', 'can:enquiries-index']])->where('type', '(members|enquiries)');
```

Just check `type` is as expected in that middleware, such as;

```
// can:enquiries-index middleware class
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->route()->parameter('type') === 'enquiries') {
        // enquiries related code blocks
    }
}

// can:members-index middleware class
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->route()->parameter('type') === 'members') {
        // members related code blocks
    }
}
```

Edit:

While using policies, it is possible to use same check block inside the service provider such `request()->route()->parameter('type')`.

Comment: Why not make a single one and check inside it?

Comment: separation of concerns @vivek_23

Comment: @vivek_23 but when you wrote i noticed a mistake - this one is easily expendable without modifying none of the classes.

Comment: @Ersoy Can I have access to route parameters in Providers. Because I'm using Gate definition for authorizing the routes. Check the updated question.

Comment: @SunnyKumar you may try to access via using `request()->route()->parameter('type')` inside your ServiceProvider - request could be resolved.

Comment: @Ersoy Yeah, I am able to access route parameter through request().

Comment: @Ersoy can you update the answer according to my code so that I can accept the answer..